# Order results by category

Tags: php, mysql

I'm trying to order my blog posts by user defined category, i.e, the one they click on my blog page.

Here's my code thus far,

```
##########################################################
$cat = mysql_real_escape_string($_GET['category']);
##########################################################

$sql = "SELECT * FROM php_blog WHERE category = $cat ORDER BY timestamp";

$result = mysql_query($sql) or print ("Can't select entry from table php_blog.<br />" . $sql . "<br />" . mysql_error());
```

But that gives me this error,

> Can't select entry from table
>   php_blog. SELECT * FROM php_blog WHERE
>   category = Update ORDER BY timestamp
>   You have an error in your SQL syntax;
>   check the manual that corresponds to
>   your MySQL server version for the
>   right syntax to use near 'Update ORDER
>   BY timestamp' at line 1 Warning:
>   mysql_fetch_array(): supplied argument
>   is not a valid MySQL result resource
>   in
>   /home/funding9/public_html/jbblog/htdocs/category.php
>   on line 91

Comment: good on you using `mysql_real_escape_string` but you forgot to surround $cat in single quotes, like so `WHERE category = '$cat'`. This means the SQL-injection hole is still open. so don't forget those extra quotes.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
$sql = "SELECT * FROM php_blog WHERE category = '" . mysql_real_escape_string($cat) . "' ORDER BY timestamp";
```

The string needed to be quoted (in your example it was Update, needs to be 'Update'), and also I ran it through mysql_real_escape_string() to protect you from SQL Injection.

Comment: Worked like a charm, much appreciated!

Answer (score 1):

MySQL uses back ticks to allow you to escape names. You should be using something like the following:

```
$cat = mysql_real_escape_string($_GET['category'], $mysql_link);
$queryString = "SELECT * FROM `php_blog` WHERE `category` = '$cat' ORDER BY `timestamp`";
```

Supplying the link will make sure it is escaped for that connection, where different databases may have different configurations and require different things to be escaped in them.

You may also want to look into the use of prepared statements with [MySQLi](http://www.php.net/manual/en/mysqli-stmt.bind-param.php) as well. That takes the difficulty out of knowing which input needs to be escaped, how it should be quoted and even some of the verification.